# IBuffer.AsStream causes Unable to cast COM object exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, com, windows-runtime, c++-cx

In my Windows Phone 8 app, I am trying to send data obtained in background agent (written in c++/cx) to foreground app(written in c#). I could successfully register a Call back and invoke the function written in C# from C++ layer (which runs in separate background process).

My C# function is

```
public virtual void OnNewAudioData(IBuffer buffer)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[buffer.Length];
    var reader = buffer.AsStream();
    reader.Read(data, 0, (int)buffer.Length);
}
```

But the function breaks on 2nd line (when I use buffer.AsStream method) with the following exception

> System.InvalidCastException occurred
>     _HResult=-2147467262
>     _message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IBufferByteAccess'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{905A0FEF-BC53-11DF-8C49-001E4FC686DA}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

[Edit : Adding more code]

My C++/CX function which invokes the C# call back is

```
void BackEndTransport::Write(BYTE* bytes, int byteCount)
{
    ComPtr<NativeBuffer> spNativeBuffer = NULL;
    MakeAndInitialize<NativeBuffer>(&spNativeBuffer, bytes, byteCount, FALSE);

    //Invoking the call back to C# layer
    Globals::Instance->CallController->OnNewAudioData(NativeBuffer::GetIBufferFromNativeBuffer(spNativeBuffer));
}
```

Implementation of NativeBuffer class is as follows (Taken from [Microsoft code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/ChatterBox-VoIP-sample-app-b1e63b8b) sample)

```
#pragma once
#include "windows.h"
#include <robuffer.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <wrl/implements.h>
#include <wrl\client.h>
#include <windows.storage.streams.h>

namespace PhoneVoIPApp
{
    namespace BackEnd
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The purpose of this class is to transform byte buffers into an IBuffer
        /// </summary>
        class NativeBuffer : public Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClass<
            Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassFlags< Microsoft::WRL::RuntimeClassType::WinRtClassicComMix >,
            ABI::Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer,
            Windows::Storage::Streams::IBufferByteAccess,
            Microsoft::WRL::FtmBase>
        {

        public:
            virtual ~NativeBuffer()
            {
                if (m_pBuffer && m_bIsOwner)
                {
                    delete[] m_pBuffer;
                    m_pBuffer = NULL;
                }
            }

            STDMETHODIMP RuntimeClassInitialize(UINT totalSize)
            {
                m_uLength = totalSize;
                m_uFullSize = totalSize;
                m_pBuffer = new BYTE[totalSize];
                m_bIsOwner = TRUE;
                return S_OK;
            }

            STDMETHODIMP RuntimeClassInitialize(BYTE* pBuffer, UINT totalSize, BOOL fTakeOwnershipOfPassedInBuffer)
            {
                m_uLength = totalSize;
                m_uFullSize = totalSize;
                m_pBuffer = pBuffer;
                m_bIsOwner = fTakeOwnershipOfPassedInBuffer;
                return S_OK;
            }

            STDMETHODIMP Buffer( BYTE **value)
            {
                *value = m_pBuffer;
                return S_OK;
            }

            STDMETHODIMP get_Capacity(UINT32 *value)
            {
                *value = m_uFullSize;
                return S_OK;
            }

            STDMETHODIMP get_Length(UINT32 *value)
            {
                *value = m_uLength;
                return S_OK;
            }

            STDMETHODIMP put_Length(UINT32 value)
            {
                if(value > m_uFullSize)
                {
                    return E_INVALIDARG;
                }
                m_uLength = value;
                return S_OK;
            }

            static Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ GetIBufferFromNativeBuffer(Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<NativeBuffer> spNativeBuffer)
            {
                auto iinspectable = reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(spNativeBuffer.Get());
                return reinterpret_cast<Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^>(iinspectable);
            }
            static BYTE* GetBytesFromIBuffer(Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ buffer)
            {
                auto iinspectable = (IInspectable*)reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(buffer);
                Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<Windows::Storage::Streams::IBufferByteAccess> spBuffAccess;
                HRESULT hr = iinspectable->QueryInterface(__uuidof(Windows::Storage::Streams::IBufferByteAccess), (void **)&spBuffAccess);
                UCHAR * pReadBuffer;
                spBuffAccess->Buffer(&pReadBuffer);
                return pReadBuffer;
            }
        private:
            UINT32 m_uLength;
            UINT32 m_uFullSize;
            BYTE* m_pBuffer;
            BOOL m_bIsOwner;
        };
    }
}
```

[Edit 2 :]
As per Hans Passant's suggestion, I tried to modify the function **GetIBufferFromNativeBuffer** to use **QueryInterface** instead of reinterpret_cast. But I am still stuck (my doubts in line with code).

```
static Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ GetIBufferFromNativeBuffer(Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<NativeBuffer> spNativeBuffer)
{
    auto myBuffer = spNativeBuffer.Get();
    IUnknown* iinspectable = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(myBuffer);

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ABI::Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer> spBuffer;
    HRESULT hr = iinspectable->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ABI::Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer), (void **) &spBuffer);

    //How can I convert ABI::Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer to Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer?
    return ....;
}
```

Comment: This is likely a bug in whatever code implemented this buffer.  It violates the requirement that implementing IBuffer also requires implementing IBufferByteAccess.  We can't see it of course.

Comment: @HansPassant what might be the workaround?

Comment: Fixing your C++/CX code of course.  We still can't see it.

Comment: I have updated the Question with more code

Comment: You cannot obtain an interface pointer with reinterpret_cast.  You know how to do it correctly, I see you using QueryInterface().

Comment: May it be the interface itself is implemented but cannot be marshalled?

Comment: @HansPassant Please read the modified question. Am I in the correct path?

Comment: I'm pretty worn from getting this question into a state where it documents the real problem.  If you want to draw attention then consider putting a bounty on it.  Good luck with it.

Comment: Fadi, I believe there is no real difference between ABI::Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer and Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer; the types are equivalent. You can reinterpret_cast between the types (I believe you need to shunt through a void* to get the cast to ^ type to work).

Something like reinterpret_cast<Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(spBuffer.Get()))

Comment: Maybe try `IBuffer.ToArray()`?